# All max elements and their postition of array

Tags: c, arrays, max, function-definition

So, for example, I have array: [1, 4, 9, 3, 9]

I need to find all max elements [9, 9] and their index [2, 4]

How can I do this? In C language

```
int i, pom, max;
max=*gradovi;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  if(*(gradovi+i)>max) {
    max=*(gradovi+i);
    pom=i;
  }
  if(*(gradovi+i)==max) {
    pom=i;
  }
}
return pom;
```

I need postions of all max elemenents, but this print just last

Comment: what is your effort so far? Are you looking for free homework service?

Comment: I need postions of all max elemenents, but this print just last

int i, pom, max; 
 max=*gradovi; 
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  if(*(gradovi+i)>max){
   max=*(gradovi+i);
            pom=i;
        }
        if(*(gradovi+i)==max){
            pom=i;
        }
 }  
    return pom;

Comment: Not too much yet. What is the question? What problem do  you have with this code.

Comment: is this a function? what do you send to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case you need a container that will store the indices of the elements with the maximum value.

You can allocate memory dynamically for such a container.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t max_elements( const int a[], size_t n, size_t **result )
{
    *result = NULL;
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        size_t max_i = 0;
        count = 1;

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[max_i] < a[i] )
            {
                max_i = i;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if ( !( a[i] < a[max_i] ) )
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }

        *result = malloc( count * sizeof( size_t ) );

        if ( *result != NULL )
        {
            for ( size_t i = max_i, j = 0; i < n && j < count; i++ )
            {
                if ( !( a[i] < a[max_i ] ) ) ( *result )[j++] = i;
            }               
        }           
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 4, 9, 3, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t *result = NULL;

    size_t count = max_elements( a, N, &result );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu: %d, ", result[i], a[result[i]] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( result );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2: 9, 4: 9,
```

If the returned value from the function is not equal to 0 but the pointer result was set to NULL then it means that there was a memory allocation error. You can check such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, it's simple solution:

```
void maks(int *gradovi, int n){ 
int i, pom, max; 
max=*gradovi; 
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    if(*(gradovi+i)>max){
        max=*(gradovi+i);
    }
    if(*(gradovi+i)==max){
        pom=i;
        printf("Najvise zarazenih je u gradu sa indeksom: %d\n", pom);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a wrong approach. The maximum value can be changed within the loop but the loop outputs indices of previous maximum values that will be less than the current maximum value. And the function does not store the indices.